# How to do Real Time Alerting in ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, real-time

We have ELK(+XPACK) for our network devices `syslog` server (source/destination IP and port). I'm trying to implement a **real-time** alerting system when `source_ip` field equals a specific IP address. How can i accomplish this with ELK?

I tried to do it with watcher, but it isn't real-time and low intervals may cause performance problems(?).

Note: log rate ~ 500 log per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If watcher are not fast enough, then you need sth. what will fire at the moment of data incoming. Ingest pipelines can't execute external actions, but if you have Logstah in place, then clone (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-clone.html) the relevant event and issue an alert via email (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-email.html) or whatever suits you.

Doing so, there will be the original event in elastic and the cloned one can be processed i a separate alert pipeline.

Comment: Good idea. I tested and it was OK till now. Let's wait to see anyone has better idea.Thanks..

Comment: With some performance optimization in Logstash and Elasticsearch, i got what i wanted. Thanks.